# How can I properly reference constants from a constants.js file from any other file in my Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got a `constants.js` file that contains export statements like:
`const domains = ['target.com', 'amazon.com', '88rising.com'];`

When I import from another file, which looks like this:

```
const domains = ['target.com', 'amazon.com', '88rising.com'];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
      
      const currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
      const truncatedUrlElement = document.getElementById('truncated-url');
      const siteIndexElement = document.getElementById('index-number');

      truncatedUrl = new URL(currentUrl).hostname.replace(/^www\./, '');
      truncatedUrlElement.textContent = truncatedUrl;
      console.log(truncatedUrl)
      
      siteIndex = domains.indexOf(truncatedUrl) + 1;
      siteIndexElement.textContent = siteIndex.toString();
    });
  });
```

`domains` actually does properly log to the console, but is not properly logging from inside the `document.addEventListener` block. I'm having a really tough time understanding why this would be the case, and how to properly reference and import constants from my `constants.js` file across my entire Chrome extension project.

Tried to import a variable from another file, `constants.js` and expected the reference to be correctly handled.

It's strangely working at the beginning of the file, but not in the middle where it needs to?

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` does not wait for modules/scripts to load. It may not seem like that's how it should work, but indeed, you're looking for `load` event in that case rather than the one you're using. Another option to consider is perhaps using promises if that would work for you. Under the hood, modules behave in a manner similar to promises. You could also try `import ( "name" )` function, which returns a promise that fulfills when the module is loaded.

Comment: Gotcha, unfortunately I'm not familiar with promises, and I'm not quite sure how to make this work

Comment: Your code wouldn't need to subscribe to an event, just use `import ( "moduleName" ).then ( function ( moduleObj ) {  /* your code, using module as object */ } )`. That will run your code as soon as the module becomes available.

See:
[Chained Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises)

[Module Namespace Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#module_namespace_object)

Comment: The code in the question does not correlate to the question itself, so the problem is unclear. To use modules in a content script see [this answer](/a/53033388). To use modules in a script that runs inside an html page you need to declare the main script as a module as shown in JavaScript tutorials for ES modules.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after some working and debugging, it seems that storing constants in a `constants.js` file is actually not a good idea. Chrome extension projects have a much easier way to store and retrieve constants using a built in method called `chrome.storage.sync`.

Here's an example of how I can set a constant for use in other files from `background.js`:

```
let domains_list = ['target.com', 'amazon.com', '88rising.com']

chrome.storage.sync.set({
  domains: domains_list
});
```

Then I can retrieve that another file, which for me is `index_state.js`, with a simple `.get`:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('domains', (result) => {
  domains = result.domains;
});
```

I found this in the documentation after struggling to use import and export methods to pass constants from one file to another properly. I hope someone can see this answer in the future and save some of the time that I spent struggling with this!